# Make error for ifeq: syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a Makefile that does string matching at one place, the code is like:

```
if test ...; \
    then \
    shell scripts... \
fi

ifeq ($(DIST_TYPE),nightly)
    shell scripts ...
endif
```

Here the first `if` is shell script, the second `ifeq` is GNU Make's conditional. However the following error generates:

> ifeq (nightly,nightly)
>
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `nightly,nightly'
>
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (nightly,nightly)'

What's happening here? It seems that Make is trying to call the shell.

Comment: You are confusing conditional statements in `sh` (such as the first) with conditional statements in `make` (such as the second).

Answer (score 343, accepted):

I played around the code and found that the conditional statements should be written without indentation, and this solved my problem.

If there is no indentation, Make will treat it as a directive for itself; otherwise, it's regarded as a shell script.

### Example code

Wrong:

```
target:
    ifeq (foo, bar)
        ...
    endif
```

Correct:

```
target:
ifeq (foo, bar)
    ...
endif
```

Answer (score 14):

In addition, if the conditional statements is used in define functions, like:

```
define myFunc
ifeq (foo, bar)
    ...
endif
endef
```

In this case, Make will also treat it as a shell script.

This problem can be solved by using if-function instead:

```
define myFunc
    $(if condition,then-part[,else-part])
endef
```

Comment: saved me lot of time :)