# Check if a program exists from a Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I check if a program is callable from a Makefile?

(That is, the program should exist in the path or otherwise be callable.)

It could be used to check for which compiler is installed, for instance.

E.g. something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script), but without assuming the underlying shell is POSIX compatible.

Comment: Can you *invoke* a POSIX-compatible shell?

Comment: Probably not, I guess I could demand one to be there, but it would be much easier if I didn't have to.

Comment: In the meantime, I solved it by adding a program to the project, which is built first, and whose sole purpose is to check for that other program... :-)

Comment: The traditional workaround is to have an `automake` script which checks various prerequisites and writes out a suitable `Makefile`.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Sometimes you need a Makefile to be able to run on different target OS's and you want the build to fail early if a required executable is not in `PATH` rather than to run for a possibly long time before failing.

The excellent solution provided by [engineerchuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262766/engineerchuan) requires making a **target**. However, if you have many executables to test and your Makefile has many independent targets, each of which requires the tests, then each target requires the test target as a dependency. That makes for a lot of extra typing as well as processing time when you make more than one target at a time.

The solution provided by [0xf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2032514/0xf) can test for an executable without making a target. That saves a lot of typing and execution time when there are multiple targets that can be built either separately or together.

My improvement to the latter solution is to use the `which` executable (`where` in Windows), rather than to rely on there being a `--version` option in each executable, directly in the GNU Make `ifeq` directive, rather than to define a new variable, and to use the GNU Make `error` function to stop the build if a required executable is not in `${PATH}`. For example, to test for the `lzop` executable:

```
 ifeq (, $(shell which lzop))
 $(error "No lzop in $(PATH), consider doing apt-get install lzop")
 endif
```

If you have several executables to check, then you might want to use a `foreach` function with the `which` executable:

```
EXECUTABLES = ls dd dudu lxop
K := $(foreach exec,$(EXECUTABLES),\
        $(if $(shell which $(exec)),some string,$(error "No $(exec) in PATH")))
```

Note the use of the `:=` assignment operator that is required in order to force immediate evaluation of the RHS expression. If your Makefile changes the `PATH`, then instead of the last line above you will need:

```
        $(if $(shell PATH=$(PATH) which $(exec)),some string,$(error "No $(exec) in PATH")))
```

This should give you output similar to:

```
ads$ make
Makefile:5: *** "No dudu in PATH.  Stop.
```

Comment: If you make EXECUTABLES all variables, (i.e. LS CC LD), and use $($(exec)), you can pass them to make seamlessly from the environment or other makefiles. Useful when cross-compiling.

Comment: My make chokes at the "," when running "ifeq (, $(shell which lzop))" =/

Comment: @mentatkgs: What version of `make` are you using, and on what OS? What error message do you see? Note that this post relates specifically to GNU `make`, not other `make` implementations.

Comment: Gnu make 4.0 on Fedora 23. The message I saw is a parse error on the ",".

Comment: @mentatkgs: Works fine on Gnu make 4.0. I suspect that you are missing the backslash after the comma, `$(EXECUTABLES),\`, or you have a space or tab character after the backslash.

Comment: On Windows, use `where my_exe 2>NUL` instead of `which`.

Comment: ```NUL``` is only available in ```cmd.exe```, a "safer" option is to use... ```where my_exe 2>&1```, which will redirect StdErr to StdOut. This works on all of the shells I know of.

Comment: Beware of TABS indentations with ifeq which is a rule syntax! it must be WITHOUT TAB. Had a hard time with that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226973/2118777

Comment: If you're using `Bash`, there's no need to make an external call to `which`. Use the built-in `command -v` instead. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/1053066).

Comment: This produces `make: which: No such file or directory` on my machine, because GNU Make bypasses the shell for simple commands, breaking shell built-ins like `which`. `$(shell command -v lzop 2>/dev/null)` is more portable.

Answer (score 81):

I mixed the solutions from @kenorb and @0xF and got this:

```
DOT := $(shell command -v dot 2> /dev/null)

all:
ifndef DOT
    $(error "dot is not available please install graphviz")
endif
    dot -Tpdf -o pres.pdf pres.dot
```

It works beautifully because "command -v" doesn't print anything if the executable is not available, so the variable DOT never gets defined and you can just check it whenever you want in your code. In this example I'm throwing an error, but you could do something more useful if you wanted.

If the variable is available, "command -v" performs the inexpensive operation of printing the command path, defining the DOT variable.

Comment: At least in some systems (i.e. Ubuntu 14.04), `$(shell command -v dot)` fails with `make: command: Command not found`. To fix this, redirect stderr output to /dev/null: `$(shell command -v dot 2> /dev/null)`. [Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12991757/882918)

Comment: I thought command was a bash builtin, so it would not cause any trouble. I'm guessing I'm wrong then.
Anyway, I have some Ubuntu 14.04 machines at work. I'm going to check that later.

Comment: `command` is a bash builtin, for more portability, consider using `which` ?

Comment: @JulienPalard I believe you're mistaken: the `command` utility is required by [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) (including the `-v` option) On the other hand `which` has no standardized bahaviour (that I know of) and is sometimes outright [unusable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/117814)

Comment: Note that the indentation is significant on macOS/OSX, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483313/make-error-for-ifeq-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token

Comment: `command -v` requires a POSIX-like shell environment. This will not work on Windows without cygwin or similar emulation.

Comment: Just want to warn that this doesn't work as part as a recipe, as `ifndef` is always evaluated. The answer from engineerchuan works better in that regard.

Comment: The reason why `command` often doesn't work is *not because of its absence*, but because of a [peculiar optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17550243) that GNU Make does: if a command is "simple enough" it will bypass the shell; this unfortunately means built-ins sometimes won't work unless you mangle the command a bit.

Comment: @J0HN While it may make sense in some specific cases to redirect errors as you mentioned, it has the downside of not behaving the same way as the original command. The correct way to force make to send your command through a shell without any side effect is to add a semicolon at the end of the arguments.

Answer (score 38):

is this what you did?

```
check: PYTHON-exists
PYTHON-exists: ; @which python > /dev/null
mytarget: check
.PHONY: check PYTHON-exists
```

credit to my coworker.

Comment: No, I compiled a program in one target and ran it in another.

Answer (score 25):

Use the `shell` function to call your program in a way that it prints something to standard output. For example, pass `--version`.

GNU Make ignores the exit status of the command passed to `shell`. To avoid the potential "command not found" message, redirect standard error to `/dev/null`.

Then you may check the result using `ifdef`, `ifndef`, `$(if)` etc.

```
YOUR_PROGRAM_VERSION := $(shell your_program --version 2>/dev/null)

all:
ifdef YOUR_PROGRAM_VERSION
    @echo "Found version $(YOUR_PROGRAM_VERSION)"
else
    @echo Not found
endif
```

As a bonus, the output (such as program version) might be useful in other parts of your Makefile.

Comment: this gives error `*** missing separator.  Stop.` If I add tabs at all lines after `all:` I get error `make: ifdef: Command not found`

Comment: also: `ifdef` will evaluate true even if `your_program` does not exist http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax

Comment: Don't add tabs to the `ifdef`, `else`, `endif` lines. Just make sure the `@echo` lines start with tabs.

Comment: I tested my solution on Windows and Linux. The documentation you linked states that `ifdef` checks for non-empty variable value. If your variable is not empty, what does it evaluate to?

Comment: @Matthias009 when I test GNU Make v4.2.1, using `ifdef` or `ifndef` (as in the accepted answer) only works if the variable being evaluated is immediately set (`:=`) instead of lazily set (`=`). However, a downside of using immediately set variables is that they are evaluated at declaration time, whereas lazily set variables are evaluated when they are called. This means you would be executing commands for variables with `:=` even when Make is only running rules that never use those variables! You can avoid this by using a `=` with `ifneq ($(MY_PROG),)`

Answer (score 16):

Cleaned up some of the existing solutions here...

```
REQUIRED_BINS := composer npm node php npm-shrinkwrap
$(foreach bin,$(REQUIRED_BINS),\
    $(if $(shell command -v $(bin) 2> /dev/null),$(info Found `$(bin)`),$(error Please install `$(bin)`)))
```

The `$(info ...)` you can exclude if you want this to be quieter.

This will **fail fast**. No target required.

Answer (score 11):

I am personally defining a `require` target which runs before all the others. This target simply runs the version commands of all requirements one at a time and prints appropriate error messages if the command is invalid.

```
all: require validate test etc

require:
    @echo "Checking the programs required for the build are installed..."
    @shellcheck --version >/dev/null 2>&1 || (echo "ERROR: shellcheck is required."; exit 1)
    @derplerp --version >/dev/null 2>&1 || (echo "ERROR: derplerp is required."; exit 1) 

# And the rest of your makefile below.
```

The output of the below script is

```
Checking the programs required for the build are installed...
ERROR: derplerp is required.
makefile:X: recipe for target 'require' failed
make: *** [require] Error 1
```

Answer (score 10):

My solution involves a little helper script<sup>1</sup> that places a flag file if all required commands exist. This comes with the advantage that the check for the required commands is only done once and not on every `make` invocation.

**check_cmds.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

NEEDED_COMMANDS="jlex byaccj ant javac"

for cmd in ${NEEDED_COMMANDS} ; do
    if ! command -v ${cmd} &> /dev/null ; then
        echo Please install ${cmd}!
        exit 1
    fi
done

touch .cmd_ok
```

**Makefile**

```
.cmd_ok:
    ./check_cmds.sh

build: .cmd_ok target1 target2
```

<sup>1</sup> More about the `command -v` technique can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script).

Comment: I just tested it and it works and since you provided no hint about what is not working for you (the bash script or the Makefile code) or any error messages I can't help you find the problem.

Comment: I'm getting "unexpected end of file" on the first `if` statement.

Answer (score 6):

For me all above answers are based on linux and are not working with windows. I'm new to make so my approach may not be ideal. But complete example that works for me on both linux and windows is this:

```
# detect what shell is used
ifeq ($(findstring cmd.exe,$(SHELL)),cmd.exe)
$(info "shell Windows cmd.exe")
DEVNUL := NUL
WHICH := where
else
$(info "shell Bash")
DEVNUL := /dev/null
WHICH := which
endif

# detect platform independently if gcc is installed
ifeq ($(shell ${WHICH} gcc 2>${DEVNUL}),)
$(error "gcc is not in your system PATH")
else
$(info "gcc found")
endif
```

optionally when I need to detect more tools I can use:

```
EXECUTABLES = ls dd 
K := $(foreach myTestCommand,$(EXECUTABLES),\
        $(if $(shell ${WHICH} $(myTestCommand) 2>${DEVNUL} ),\
            $(myTestCommand) found,\
            $(error "No $(myTestCommand) in PATH)))
$(info ${K})
```

Comment: I've never thought someone would use GNU Make with the dreaded cmd.exe ... "shell".

Answer (score 4):

You can use bash built commands such as `type foo` or `command -v foo`, as below:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
all: check

check:
        @type foo
```

Where `foo` is your program/command. Redirect to `> /dev/null` if you want it silent.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is I wanted it to work when I had only GNU make but no bash installed.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have different targets and builders, each requires another set of tools.
Set a list of such tools and consider them as target to force checking their availability

For example:

```
make_tools := gcc md5sum gzip

$(make_tools):  
    @which $@ > /dev/null

file.txt.gz: file.txt gzip
    gzip -c file.txt > file.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions checking for `STDERR` output of `--version` does not work for programs which print their version to `STDOUT` instead of `STDERR`. Instead of checking their output to `STDERR` or `STDOUT`, check for the program return code. If the program does not exist, its exit code will always be non zero.

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123241/makefile-as-an-executable-script-with-shebang
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e
SHELL := /bin/bash

RESULT := $(shell python --version >/dev/null 2>&1 || (echo "Your command failed with $$?"))

ifeq (,${RESULT})
    EXISTS := true
else
    EXISTS := false
endif

all:
    echo EXISTS: ${EXISTS}
    echo RESULT: ${RESULT}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by compiling a special little program in another makefile target, whose sole purpose is to check for whatever runtime stuff I was looking for.

Then, I called this program in yet another makefile target.

It was something like this if I recall correctly:

```
real: checker real.c
    cc -o real real.c `./checker`

checker: checker.c
    cc -o checker checker.c
```

Comment: Thank you. But this would abort make, right? Is it possible to prevent make from aborting? I'm trying to skip a build step if the required tool is not available..

Comment: @coding.mof edited - it was more like that. The program checked something in the runtime and gave info accordingly to the rest of the compile.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but here is my take on that question

```
CMD_NOT_FOUND = $(error $(1) is required for this rule)
CHECK_CMD = $(if $(shell command -v $(1)),,$(call CMD_NOT_FOUND,$(1)))
```

you can either apply it globally:

```
$(call CHECK_CMD,gcc)
```

or within a specific rule:

```
do_stuff:
    $(call CHECK_CMD,md5sum)
```

or within a for loop

```
REQUIREMENTS := gcc md5sum gzip
 
$(foreach req,$(REQUIREMENTS),$(call CHECK_CMD,$(req)))
```

Answer (score 1):

even later, got here while searching an answer

... but then I tried something else (on Linux) ...

--8<----8<----8<--

```
zig := $(word 1,$(foreach var,$(subst :, ,$(PATH)),$(wildcard $(var)/zig)))

ifdef zig
$(info $(zig) defined)
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following, inspired by other answers in this topic and *StackOverflow* and similar sites:

### `Makefile`

ℹ️ *(This is just the top of `Makefile`'s i will create self...)*

```makefile
#   SPDX-License-Identifier: CC-BY-NC-SA-4.0
#
SHELL = /usr/bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS = -ec
.ONESHELL:
.SILENT:

UTILS           :=
UTILS           += setfacl
UTILS           += chown
UTILS           += chmod
# UTILS         += nonexisting
include CheckUtils.mk
```

1. Line #3 defines the shell to use, you can uncomment this to use the default `sh`.
2. Lines #9-12 define the utils you want to be checked.
3. Line #13 includes the below file.

### `CheckUtils.mk`

ℹ️ *Bug report wrt highlighting: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3878*

ℹ️ [The latest version of this file](https://gitlab.com/trimoon-inc/system/systemd-PPPoE/-/blob/main/CheckUtils.mk) is available in one-of-my repo's at GitLab.

```make
#   SPDX-License-Identifier: CC-BY-NC-SA-4.0
#   Version: 2023-11-14
#
# This make-snippet will both check for the utils you define AND
#   automatically create an uppercase variable with the util name
#   for you to use in the rest of your Makefile(s).
#
# Usage:
#   The utils to be used should be put inside the UTILS var,
#   separated by space. Example:
#   UTILS   :=
#   UTILS   += setfacl
#   UTILS   += chown
#   UTILS   += chmod
#   # UTILS += nonexisting
#   include CheckUtils.mk
#
# Explanation of workings:
#   Lines #50-51, #86, #88:
#       For use in recursive make's.
#       Makes sure that the code inside this make-snippet is only applied ONCE.
#   Line #52:
#       Feedback header
#   Lines #54-60:
#       Creates a macro for uppercase conversion.
#       It auto-selects from two versions, which you can extend as needed.
#       The first, bash variant, uses ${VAR^^}.
#       The last, non-bash variant eg sh, uses sed.
#   Lines #64, #74:
#       Is to prevent checking and defining the SHELL itself,
#           but allow it to be displayed in the feedback. 
#       (The shell is included as first util to check in line #63)
#   Lines #66-71:
#       Is to let make auto-create the respective variable(s) in uppercase
#           with the found executable as value.
#       The export in line #67 makes the created variable(s) available in
#           recursive make's without re-processing.
#   Line #72 in combo with #65/#73:
#       Aborts the make with an error if the requested util can not be found.
#   Lines #75-83:
#       Provide feedback about which util was found and where.
#       The output is nicely right-aligned when the length of the util-name
#           is <=20 (Line #78)
#   Lines #84-85:
#       Feedback footer
#
# Cross-posted-at:
#   https://stackoverflow.com/a/77223358/22510042

# For recorsive invocations.
ifndef CheckUtils
$(info ### START: Utils check)

# Define macro w.r.t. shell in use.
ifeq (bash,$(findstring bash,$(SHELL)))
toUpper = $(shell string="$(strip $1)"; printf "%s" $${string^^})
else
# Insipred by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660916/22510042
toUpper = $(shell echo "$(strip $1)" | sed 's/.*/\U&/')
endif

# Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37197276/22510042
$(foreach util,shell $(UTILS),\
    $(if $(filter-out shell,$(util)),\
        $(if $(shell command -v $(util) 2>/dev/null),\
            $(eval $(strip \
                export \
                $(call toUpper,$(util) )\
                :=\
                $(shell command -v $(util) 2>/dev/null)\
            ))\
            ,$(error No '$(util)' in PATH)\
        )\
    )\
    $(info \
        $(shell \
            printf "%*s = '%s'" \
                20 \
                "$(call toUpper,$(util))" \
                "$($(call toUpper,$(util)))"\
        )\
    )\
)
$(info ### END: Utils check)
$(info ) # Empty line
export CheckUtils:=1    # Mark already applied for recorsive invocations.
# $(error END: Utils check, forced for debuging this snippet)
endif
```

### Output

- `make` without any changes will be similar to:

  ```
  ### START: Utils check
  SHELL   = /usr/bin/bash
  SETFACL = /usr/bin/setfacl
  CHOWN   = /usr/bin/chown
  CHMOD   = /usr/bin/chmod
  ### END: Utils check
  ```
- With the `nonexisting` **util** uncommented. will be similar to:

  ```
  ### START: Utils check
  SHELL   = /usr/bin/bash
  SETFACL = /usr/bin/setfacl
  CHOWN   = /usr/bin/chown
  CHMOD   = /usr/bin/chmod
  Makefile:21: *** No 'nonexisting' in PATH.  Stop.
  ```

---

Hope this will be useful to others, it will at least serve as a backup for myself