# Calling `command -v find` from GNU Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I use a shell (bash, but I need portability) and a GNU Makefile. I have this code:

```
check_commands:
        command -v find >/dev/null
        command -v asdf >/dev/null
```

As supposed, the first command is passed, the second aborts the Makefile with an error. Now, I remove the `>/dev/null`. Why does then

```
check_commands:
        command -v find
```

produce the following error?

```
make: command: Command not found.
```

Comment: What happens if you try `command -v find` on the command line?

Comment: @Beta it outputs `/usr/bin/find`, as desired.

Comment: Note: `sh -c command -v find` outputs nothing for me, but returns 0 aswell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Judging from a quick look at `job.c` in GNU make's sources, it attempts to avoid launching a shell when it can, i.e. when the command line is simple enough (of the form `cmd args`, without redirection, compound commands, etc.) and the shell is the default one. The issue is then that `command` is a built-in and does not have an associated executable, hence the error message from make. It does not occur when you have `> /dev/null` as make considers the command as too complicated and leaves it to `sh` to launch it.