# How to use shell builtin function from a Makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

I just stumbled on this problem. I tried to write a very basic `Makefile` target:

```
core: myprogram
        ulimit -c 10000
        ./myprogram
        ulimit -c 0
```

The idea is to set up the core size limit to a proper value, make the program crash and then reset the core size limit back to zero. When I am calling this rule, I get the following error message:

```
$ make core
cc -Wall -Wextra -m32 -g  -o example example.c 
ulimit -c 100000
make: ulimit: Command not found
make: *** [core] Error 127
```

First, I have been a bit surprised, but I think that the problem is coming from the fact that `ulimit` is a shell builtin. And, suprisingly (at least for me), these builtin functions cannot be called from a `Makefile`.

Moreover, `ulimit` can be both a builtin function only (it is the case on my Debian) **or** a binary program only (`/usr/bin/ulimit`).

So, my question is simple, how to workaround this problem, if possible in an **elegant and portable manner**, and call the builtin function from the inside of a Makefile ?

Comment: No, `ulimit` is *not* a shell builtin. (How **possibly could** it be one, given the functionality it provides?)

Comment: Then why do I have an `/usr/bin/ulimit` executable?

Comment: These are two different things. It is like `test` or others. Many builtin functions duplicate a binary program. But, this is the builtin function that is used first.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that make (GNU make in particular) tries to perform a number of optimizations.  One of those is that if the command *appears* to be a simple command that does not require the shell, then make will simply invoke it directly via fork/exec and not run a shell.  If the command only exists as a shell built-in, then this will not work.  Your command line `ulimit -c 10000` is a simple command and ulimit is not defined as only a shell-builtin that make knows about, so make will try to fork/exec `ulimit` directly.  So a way to get around your immediate issue is to simply add a character that's special to the shell (the most obvious one is `;`), which will hint to make that this command needs to be sent to the shell.

However, this will not work for you.

Exactly contrary to H2CO3's comment above: *How possibly could it be [a shell builtin], given the functionality it provides?* the real question you have to ask yourself is the opposite: *how possibly could it NOT be one, given the functionality it provides?*  The man page for ulimit clearly states: *The  ulimit  utility  shall  set  or report the file-size writing limit imposed on files written by the shell and its child processes*, and further: *Since  ulimit  affects  the  current shell execution environment, it is always provided as a shell regular built-in.*

You have to remember that it's virtually impossible for a process in UNIX to modify ANY aspect of its parent process.  It can only modify itself, or any child processes that it invokes.  This includes the environment variables, working directory, and it also includes ulimit settings.

So, good, how does this apply to your situation?  You have to remember that each logical line in a make recipe is invokes in a *separate shell*.  So for a command like:

```
core: myprogram
        ulimit -c 10000 ;
        ./myprogram
        ulimit -c 0 ;
```

(adding the semicolons to force a shell) what make basically invokes is this:

```
core: myprogram
        /bin/sh -c 'ulimit -c 10000 ;'
        /bin/sh -c './myprogram'
        /bin/sh -c 'ulimit -c 0 ;'
```

As you can see, each ulimit is invoked in its own shell, so it's effectively useless.  It will modify the core file size limit for that shell, then the shell exits and the change is lost, then your program is invoked in a new shell with the original ulimit, then a third shell is invoked and ulimit for cores is set to 0 (also useless).

What you need to do is put all of these commands on a single logical line, like this:

```
core: myprogram
        ulimit -c 10000; ./myprogram
```

(you don't need to set the limit back, because the shell will exit anyway).

As a side note, *this* is why make doesn't worry too much about these shell builtins.  A builtin like this is basically impossible to use to any effect in a context where you *don't* need to use some special shell character like a semicolon.

Comment: @perror: He's right, you know... I merely thought about the generic "builtin vs. external" problem, not the implications of `ulimit` in specific. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Dear MadScientist, this is really a brilliant answer. And, this is also exactly what I meant by *elegance*. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks, you save my time.

Comment: thanks , and “What you need to do is put all of these commands on a single logical line” that sound like layer stuff in Dockerfile

Answer (score 3):

The default shell for any `Makefile` is `sh`. If you have to use builtins of a specific shell, specify that shell in your `Makefile`:

```
SHELL:=bash
```

Note that this is *bad* practice, because the idea is that your `Makefile` should work on *any* machine, not only those with `bash` installed.

If you want to support either variant (external vs. builtin), you can check for the availability of `bash` resp. `ulimit` via `which`, and set a variable containing the command to use (`ulimit` vs. `bash -c "ulimit"`) depending on the outcome of that check.

**Edit:** MadScientist is absolutely right about the "current shell only" aspect of `ulimit`. I'll keep this answer intact for documentation purposes, but it doesn't help with perror's specific problem.

Comment: I agree with you, this is a bad practice because it is not portable (one of my user is using NetBSD with `sh`, so I can't afford to do what you say).

Comment: @perror: You can check for the availability of `bash` resp. `ulimit` via `which`, and set a variable containing the command to use (`ulimit` vs. `bash -c "ulimit"`) depending on the outcome.

Comment: Yes, I will try this. But, it seems a bit like a *brute-force* solution to me. Is there really no hope to do something elegant ? :-)

Comment: @perror: It's not really brute force. Consider: You are in a `sh` environment. There are two ways of getting what you want, one via the executable `bash`, one via the executable `ulimit`. You have to check which one is available... and there is no "more elegant" way to do it than via `which` (which is the tool built for just this purpose).

Comment: Well, *brute-force* is probably not well chosen, but this case enumeration is just a bit risky for me. We never know if a new case will come one day and break everything.

Comment: But, it seems to be another problem. When I am trying the rule, I got the following error: `/bin/bash: line 0: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted`. Is `ulimit` requiring root's rights through a setuid ?

Comment: This issue is not related in any way to the shell that's being invoked (`ulimit` is a completely portable, POSIX-specified command and not specific to bash in any way), and using /bin/bash won't help.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
core: myprogram
        $(shell /bin/bash -c "ulimit -c 10000")
        ./myprogram
        $(shell /bin/bash -c "ulimit -c 0")
```

Comment: Is the `$shell()` wrapper really necessary in a command line? Isn't it intended for use in variable assignments?

Comment: Again, this force the usage of `/bin/bash`, I need a solution that will work both on systems that have a binary `ulimit` and a builtin `ulimit`... Sorry.

Comment: There are easier (and more portable) ways to force a shell than using `$(shell ...)`, but anyway this won't help.  See my answer.

Comment: @MadScientist I agree, the proposed method is more of a hack.

Comment: This is broken! Make stores the entire block of shell commands as a single recursively expanded variable. At the point that it decides it has to run the block, it expands it. At this point, _both_ `$(shell ...)` lines are expanded. Now make has a single string left, `./myprogram`, and it passes that to the shell (after _both_ `ulimit` commands have run)

Answer (score 0):

In the official GNU make document(http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) Chapter 5.3.2, it says "The program used as the shell is taken from the variable SHELL. If this variable is not set in your makefile, the program /bin/sh is used as the shell. "
You can set SHELL to /bin/bash.

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer**: add a semicolon (;) on the end of the command. In this way you will invoke FULL shell with builtin tools.

```
        ulimit -c 10000;
```

instead of

```
        ulimit -c 10000
```