# Makefile: use $exe1 if exists else $exe2

Tags: python, bash, makefile

In bash I can do something like this in order to check if a program exists:

```
if type -P vim > /dev/null; then
    echo "vim installed"
else
    echo "vim not installed"
fi
```

I would like to do the same thing in a Makefile. 
In details I would like to choose "python3" if installed, else "python" (2). My Makefile looks like this:

```
PYTHON    = python
TSCRIPT   = test/test_psutil.py

test:
    $(PYTHON) $(TSCRIPT)
```

Is there anything I can do to use a conditional around that `PYTHON = python` line? I understand Makefiles can be told to use bash syntax somehow (`SHELL:=/bin/bash`?) but I'm no expert.

Comment: You could add a helper script in your directory: `PYTHON=./py2or3`. And in `py2or3` do the `type -P` trick.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing is probably to use `$(shell)` to figure out if `python3` is callable:

```
ifeq ($(shell which python3),)
  PYTHON = python
else
  PYTHON = python3
endif
```

`$(shell which python 3)` runs `which python3` in a shell and expands to the output of that command. That is the path of `python3` if it is available, and otherwise it is empty. This can be used in a conditional.

Addendum: About the portability concerns in the comments: the reason that `$(shell type -P python3)` does not work is that GNU make attempts to optimize away the shell call and fork/exec itself, which does not work with a shell builtin. I found this out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547625/how-to-use-shell-builtin-function-from-a-makefile). If your `/bin/sh` knows `type -P`, then

```
# note the semicolon  -------v
ifeq ($(shell type -P python3;),)
```

works. My `/bin/sh` is `dash`, though, so that didn't work for me (it complained about -P not being a valid command). What did work was

```
ifeq ($(shell type python3;),)
```

because `dash`'s type sends the error message about unavailable commands to stderr, not stdout (so the `$(shell)` expands to the empty string). If you can depend on `which`, I think doing that is the cleanest way. If you can depend on bash, then

```
ifeq ($(shell bash -c 'type -P python3'),)
```

also works. Alternatively,

```
SHELL = bash

ifeq ($(shell type -P python3;),)
```

has the same effect. If none of those are an option, desperate measures like @MadScientist's answer become attractive.

Or, if all else fails, you can resort to searching the path yourself:

```
PYTHON = $(shell IFS=:; for dir in $$PATH; do if test -f "$$dir/python3" && test -x "$$dir/python3"; then echo python3; exit 0; fi; done; echo python)
```

This is lifted from the way `autoconf`'s `AC_CHECK_PROG` is implemented. I'm not sure whether I'd want this, though.

Comment: `which` is pesky. The OP's choice of `type` is POSIX and standard.

Comment: Hm. It's in a package called "debianutils". Fair enough; changed.

Comment: The `type` command itself is POSIX, but using `-P` is not POSIX.  In fact, there's nothing much standardized about the `type` command; POSIX doesn't mention any options, doesn't specify the output format, and doesn't even clearly define what errors exist: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html

Comment: This doesn't work. The "ifeq ($(shell type -P python3),)" clause is always satisfied, no matter what (also if you replace "python3" with "foobar")

Comment: Oh, interesting. `$(shell)` doesn't work with the builtin -- that's what I get for not testing it again. It works with `which`, so I guess I'll go back to that. Portability is then diminished, I suppose.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547625/how-to-use-shell-builtin-function-from-a-makefile seems relevant (GNU make attempts bad optimizations). `$(shell bash -c 'type -P python3')` works, as does `$(shell type python3 2>/dev/null)`, but I've seen prettier things.

Comment: None of the above (your edited response) works on Solaris (it does on Linux though). It seem a cross platform solution really is impossible to reach.

Comment: I have one more trick (see newest edit), but it's not pretty. I think @MadScientist's answer should work on both as well, though, and while I'd like to avoid spawning python3 to see whether it is there, I can't say I like this last trick better, so you may want to go with that.

Comment: Again, the last trick works on Linux but not on FreeBSD and Solaris. I conclude it's just not possible to do this in a cross-platform fashion. Thanks for your effort anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to be more portable you can try invoking the command itself to see if it works or not:

```
PYTHON := $(shell python3 --version >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo python3 || echo python)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PYTHON := $(shell type -P python3 || echo "python")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`command -v`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html):

```
PYTHON := $(shell command -v python3 2> /dev/null || echo python)
```

In Bash, `command` is a builtin command.

The example above is for GNU Make. Other Make programs may have a different syntax for running shell commands.