# Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")?

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

```
PLATFORM = x86
CUD = cuda
X86 = x86
PAN = panda
ARM = arm

app: 
    ifeq($(PLATFORM),$(CUD))
CC = dum3
endif
ifeq($(PLATFORM), $(X86))
CC = gcc
endif
ifeq($(PLATFORM),$(PAN))
CC = dum1
endif
ifeq($(PLATFORM),$(ARM))
CC = dum2
endif


$(CC) -o ./Executable/list  ./Source/ll_main.c ./Library/liblst.a
./Executable/list
```

When I `make` this, it throws the error....
`Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Please help fix this problem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The formatting in your question (both the makefile and the error message) is too messed up to be sure, but my suspicion is that your `ifeq` is indented with a TAB.

That's not right; `ifeq` is a *make* command.  (Almost) all lines with TAB characters as the first character on the line in a makefile is passed to the *shell*.  The shell doesn't know anything about `ifeq`, so, depending on your shell, might print an error like that.

You should move the `app:` target after the `ifeq` blocks to just before the use of `$(CC)` (and ensure the `$(CC) ...` line is indented with a TAB as the first character on that line).

In the future please be sure to use SO's formatting capabilities, *and* be sure to cut and paste error messages exactly, plus a few lines of context before and after, when asking questions.

Comment: I just encountered this. Don't have hard-tabs (or spaces) leading before an `ifeq` or Makefile statement. The code looks ugly with a lack of indentation, but it fixes this issue.

Comment: You can use spaces before `ifeq` or other Makefile statements.  Only a real TAB as the first character on the line could cause problems.  However I disagree that the code looks "ugly"; in fact it's extremely misleading to indent makefile statements to the same level as recipe lines; it implies they are shell commands when clearly they are not.  But you could indent 4 spaces or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error as well and in my case it was the gcc itself, or better myself: I have downloaded a linux gcc for a linux but it was a 80386 program and my linux ran on an ARM system. Try call the gcc exactly as mentioned in your makefile. If you get an error saying that the file is not an executable, then you'll know.