# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this `Makefile`:

```
TMP_DIR := tmp
RUN_OR_NOT := $(shell date '+%y%m%d%H%M')

all: version

version:
    ifeq ($(shell test -d ${TMP_DIR} && echo -n "yes";),yes)
        $(shell echo ${TMP_DIR} already exists ...)
    else
        $(shell mkdir -p ${TMP_DIR})
    endif
```

I want to first check, if the directory `tmp` exists or not, and create it only, if it does not exist. This works, but with a strange error:

```
 ifeq (yes,yes)
 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
 Makefile:7: die Regel für Ziel „version“ scheiterte
 make: *** [version] Fehler 2
```

Why is there this strange `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")` error? And how to solve this?

Comment: That looks like it should just be `version: ${TMP_DIR}` and `${TMP_DIR}: ; mkdir -p ${TMP_DIR}`.

Comment: `mkdir -p` creates the directory only if it does not already exist.

Comment: FYI, the behavior of `echo -n` is not POSIX-defined (POSIX explicitly *allows* an `echo` to modify its behavior based on a `-n` flag -- contrast with `echo -e`, which is in violation if it doesn't print `-e` on output -- but doesn't specify its behavior when that flag is given). Consider using `printf %s foo` instead of `echo -n foo`.

Answer (score 7):

In a makefile, the recipe is a shell script.  You are trying to put make constructs like `ifeq` into your recipe.  Make will pass those to the shell and the shell throws this error because it doesn't understand makefile syntax.

You should write your recipe using shell scripting, not makefile syntax:

```
version:
        if test -d ${TMP_DIR}; then \
            echo ${TMP_DIR} already exists ...; \
        else \
            mkdir -p ${TMP_DIR}; \
        fi
```

Although why you care if the directory exists already I don't know; I would personally just use:

```
version:
        mkdir -p ${TMP_DIR}
```

Comment: One can add: `version: ${TMP_DIR}\n${TMP_DIR}:\n    mkdir ${TMP_DIR}` too. (the comment markup ate my whitespaces, but I hope you know what I mean)

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is still Unanswered,

You have put a TAB after the line -> version: (before ifeq). Try using space there instead.
The lines which start with TAB character in Makefile is passed to the Shell.
Below link has the exact answer as to why it works.

[Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226905)