# Makefile - If condition

Tags: makefile, clang

I'm trying to make a condition in a Makefile that if it is the file `ft_utils.c` it compiles with a different command.

```
$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o: $(DIR_SRC)/%.c
                mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJ)
                ifeq($<, $(DIR_SRC)/ft_utils.c)
                    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -I. -o $@
                else
                    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -I. -I$(DIR_MLX) -L$(DIR_MLX) -L. $(LFLAGS) -o $@
                endif
```

But when it gets to the ft_utils.c it runs the command in the else.

How can I make an if condition in Makefile that if `$< == $(DIR_SRC)/ft_utils.c` it runs the command that I want?

Comment: Please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226905/syntax-error-word-unexpected-expecting/21226973#21226973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way. The simplest is to create an ordinary rule for that case:

```
$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o: $(DIR_SRC)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -I. -I$(DIR_MLX) -L$(DIR_MLX) -L. 

$(DIR_OBJ)/fc_utils.o: $(DIR_SRC)/fc_utils.c
    mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -I. -o $@
```

There are more sophisticated approaches, useful if you have several special targets, but try the simple approach first.

Comment: O tried this. But I was getting another problem. This obj are a depence from another command which creates a lib. When I put the 2 cases as dependency `$(LIB): $(DIR_OBJ)/fc_utils.o $(OBJ)` It only runs the first dependency and it stops the rest.

Comment: @WincentyBertoniLech: That is a separate problem (one question per Question, please), but if you post the entire `$(LIB)` rule then maybe I can help you.