# how do i fix this error when checking os in makefile?

Tags: makefile, operating-system

i was trying to add a .exe extention to my code if the os was windows.
makefile code:

```
check_os:
    ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
        g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
    else
        g++ hello.cpp -o hello
    endif

all: check_os
```

but i get this error:

```
ifeq (Windows_NT,Windows_NT)
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ifeq (Windows_NT,Windows_NT), ...) failed.
make (e=2): Systemet finner ikke angitt fil.
make: *** [Makefile:2: check_os] Error 2
```

i tried searching it up but i couldn't find any good answers

Comment: To understand this better take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712585/when-to-use-space-or-tab-in-makefile/28720186#28720186 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226905/syntax-error-word-unexpected-expecting/21226973#21226973

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove one layer of padding:

```
check_os:
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    echo windows
else
    echo not windows
endif


all: check_os
```

`ifeq` is now one TAB lower