# Check if a program exists from a Makefile, otherwise run command

Tags: makefile

I would like to create a Makefile that recognizes if a given program exists in the system and run another target (or commands) if not. Please, read my *post scriptum* (P.S.) at the end of the question before mark it as duplicated.

**In summary, I would like do something like the following pseudocode:**

```
if (myProgram.exists()):
    myProgram arg0 arg1 arg2
else:
    otherProgram arg0 arg1 arg2 #suppose that otherProgram will always exists
```

I've tried some solutions following the best answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618615/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-makefile), that tells me to do something like that:

```
check: ; @which myProgram > /dev/null
mytarget: check
    myProgram arg0 arg1 arg2
```

The solution actually works, but **this aborts the program instead of executing another makefile target / command**. I tried a lot of different implementations, but none solved my issue.

### How can I achieve something like that in a Makefile?

*P.S: this question isn't a duplicated question from "[Check if a program exists from a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618615/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-makefile)" because the latter aims to stop execution if the program doesn't exist, while the former aims to run another target if the program doesn't exist.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A general use case:

It's pretty easy to do something like that in a Makefile (for simple problems; complex problems demands more attention and maybe another solution).

For your example, the following code will do the trick:

```
run: check
    myProgram arg0 arg1 arg2

check: 
    @type myProgram >/dev/null 2>&1 || otherProgram arg0 arg1 arg2
```

Of course, you should modify it for your problem. In order to help you, following you can read a real use case from a project of mine.

---

### A real use case:

Now let's see a real use case taken from [this small graph implementation in Python](https://github.com/paladini/UFSC-graphs-2015-02/blob/f658f56307e9c420b46b7da9ad87887bc4cda9d1/liasis-graph/makefile). I've write some tests with `unittest` in a way that (a) I can execute it directly from Python or (b) can execute it from [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The latter has more verbosity, so it's better for testing purposes.

To run (a) I need something like `python mytest.py`. For (b) I need something like `nosetests -v mytest.py`. Take a look at my `makefile`:

```
all: run_tests

run_tests: check
    nosetests -v test_digraph.py 
    nosetests -v test_not_digraph.py

check: 
    @type nosetests >/dev/null 2>&1 || /usr/bin/env python test_digraph.py
    @type nosetests >/dev/null 2>&1 || /usr/bin/env python test_not_digraph.py
```

This makefile will check if `nosetests` exists, if not it will execute the tests directly from Python (using `/usr/bin/env python test_digraph.py`). If `nosetests` exists, then it will execute the instructions from `run_tests` target (in other words, `nosetests -v test_digraph.py` and `nosetests -v test_not_digraph.py`).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why would you bother with the separate target for this? Why not just do this in a single target? `@type nosetests ... && nosetests\n`@type nosetests ... || python`?

Comment: could you extend that?

Answer (score 6):

You can put arbitrary pieces of shell script in your code.  It makes sense to define the command only once, though.

```
COMMAND:=$(shell type -p foo || echo bar)
```

will set `COMMAND` to `foo` if it exists, otherwise to `bar`.

Similar snippets can be embedded in a target if you like, but you probably will want to avoid code duplication.

```
target: prerequisites
    { type -p foo && foo $^ || bar $^; } >$@
```

As you probably already know, `ack && ick || poo` is shorthand for `if ack; then ick; else poo; fi`

Comment: `$(shell ...)` is obviously a GNU Make extension.  If your platform is not GNU Make, it probably supports a different syntax, or you can use the embedded target technique as a workaround (mabe define it as a macro then).