# How to send form values to a backend Flask?

Tags: ajax, flask

I have heard that we can do this with ajax for it, but how do we achieve it? Please give a brief explanation of it.

Comment: Have you search for it?

Answer (score -1):

Example Form:

```
<form role="form" action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/login" method="post" name="loginform">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Login</legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form><form role="form" action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/login" method="post" name="loginform">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Login</legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

If you want to use Javascript `ajax` call from front-end to back-end:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/login',
        success: function(res) {
            return 'success';
        }
    })
```

tangle-make:

```
#SHELL := /bin/bash
BUILD_DIR=build

VER_BRANCH=build-release
VER_FILE=VERSION

ORG_MODE_DIR=~/emacs/lisp
LITERATE_TOOLS="https://github.com/vlead/literate-tools.git"
LITERATE_DIR=literate-tools
ELISP_DIR=elisp
ORG_DIR=org-templates
STYLE_DIR=style
CODE_DIR=build/code
DOC_DIR=build/docs
SRC_DIR=src
PWD=$(shell pwd)
STATUS=0

all:  check-org build

check-org:
ifeq ($(wildcard ${ORG_MODE_DIR}/org-8.2.10/*),)
    mkdir -p ${ORG_MODE_DIR}
    wget http://orgmode.org/org-8.2.10.tar.gz
    tar zxvf org-8.2.10.tar.gz
    rm -rf org-8.2.10.tar.gz
    mv org-8.2.10 ${ORG_MODE_DIR}
else
    @echo "org-mode org-8.2.10 already present"
endif


build: init write-version
    emacs  --script elisp/publish.el

init: mk-symlinks
    rm -rf ${BUILD_DIR}
    mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR} ${CODE_DIR}


mk-symlinks:  pull-literate-tools
    (ln -sf ${LITERATE_DIR}/${ELISP_DIR}; \
    ln -sf ../${LITERATE_DIR}/${ORG_DIR} ${SRC_DIR}; \
    ln -sf ../${LITERATE_DIR}/${STYLE_DIR} ${SRC_DIR})

pull-literate-tools:
    @echo "checking for literate support ..."
    echo "pwd=..."
    echo ${PWD}
ifeq ($(wildcard ${LITERATE_DIR}),)
    @echo "proxy is..."
    echo $$http_proxy
    (git clone ${LITERATE_TOOLS})
else
    @echo "Literate support code already present"
endif

# variable that will exist of git command exists
# solution from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618615/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-makefile
GIT_EXISTS := $(shell command -v git 2> /dev/null)

# get the latest commit hash and its subject line
# and write that to the VERSION file
write-version:
ifdef GIT_EXISTS
    # allow these to fail since the parent folder may not have a git repo.
    echo -n "Built from commit: " > ${CODE_DIR}/${VER_FILE}
    - echo `git rev-parse HEAD` >> ${CODE_DIR}/${VER_FILE}
    - echo `git log --pretty=format:'%s' -n 1` >> ${CODE_DIR}/${VER_FILE}
endif
clean-literate:
    rm -rf ${ELISP_DIR}
    rm -rf src/${ORG_DIR}
    rm -rf src/${STYLE_DIR}
    rm -rf ${LITERATE_DIR}


clean:  clean-literate
    rm -rf ${BUILD_DIR}
```