# make error (Windows) : line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `,'

Tags: shell, syntax, makefile, syntax-error, gnu-make

I'm a starter at this(make), and having some problems trying to grep for a text in a file (as part of the make process on Windows). The larger problem I'm trying to solve is to check whether all binary executables in a given directory have their respective dependencies satisfied. I use depends.exe (Dependency Walker) for the later part, whose output file I'm trying to grep, and possibly abort the build process if the dependency validation fails.

```
binary-dependency-validate:
for BINARYEXEC in $(shell $(PATH_TO_FIND_EXE) $(PRE_DEFINED_DIR) -name "*.exe"); do \
   $(PATH_TO_DEPENDS_EXE) /c /pb /ot $(PRE_DEFINED_DIR)/$$BINARYEXEC-depends.txt $(PRE_DEFINED_DIR)/$$BINARYEXEC ; \
   ifeq ($(shell $(PATH_TO_GREP_EXE) "Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found." $(PRE_DEFINED_DIR)/$$BINARYEXEC-depends.txt),); \
      @echo "Dependency ok" ; \
   endif ; \
done
```

I'm encountering the following error :

```
line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `,'
```

Any suggestions would greatly help. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483313/make-error-for-ifeq-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token) post and tried aligning ifeq without indentation as well (that didn't help either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing *Make* language with *shell* language.

A makefile contains rules, and a rule contains commands which are executed by a shell:

```
target:
    first command
    second command
```

The commands are in shell language, and each command must be preceded by a TAB.

There are conditionals in Make:

```
ifeq (foo, bar)
  VAR = something      
endif
```

(The indentation is just for the eye.)

There are also conditionals in the various scripting languages:

```
if [ -f log ]
  then
    echo "log exists."
fi
```

A Make conditional can enclose a command within a rule:

```
target:
ifeq (foo, bar)
    first command
endif
    second command
```

Make will evaluate this conditional before running the rule, and **there must be no TAB before `ifeq` or `endif`, because Make must not interpret them as commands to be passed to the shell.**

A command (in a rule) can contain a shell conditional:

```
target:
    if [ -f log ]; \
  then echo "log exists." ; \
  fi
```

The indentation before `if` is a TAB. The other whitespace is for the eye.

Your makefile has a Make conditional in the middle of a shell command; Make can't evaluate the conditional before the command executes, and the shell can't understand Make syntax. **You should use a shell conditional.**

Comment: Thanks, Beta (for the detailed explanation too). I had this problem fixed when I used shell conditional instead. But I have one another problem lingering. When I run make, 'grep' command commences always before the target, and hence $$BINARYEXEC is empty when grep is run. Even though the for loop iterates through fine, grep is never recomputed per iteration.And the error gotten is : "grep: <PATH>/-depends.txt: No such file or directory". I must be missing some subtle thing about how make processes these commands. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: By pure experimentation, I'm seeing that anything that is marked to be run in a shell is being processed(and executed) ahead of the rest of the commands. Hence, I changed $(shell $(PATH_TO_GREP) ...) to just $(PATH_TO_GREP) ...., pulled it all out of the if condition and now my shell conditional that follows looks like this : if [[ $$? -eq 0 ]]. And this has worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @durden83, again you were putting Make language (`$(shell ...)`) inside a command.

Comment: :I agree, I was just encouraged initially by looking other parts of the code (where it happened to work). I realized this and removed the Make language part from the command. Thanks for the explanation, though - it helped much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a stray comma on the ifeq line

```
binary-dependency-validate:
for BINARYEXEC in $(shell $(PATH_TO_FIND_EXE) $(PRE_DEFINED_DIR) -name "*.exe"); do \
   $(PATH_TO_DEPENDS_EXE) /c /pb /ot $(PRE_DEFINED_DIR)/$$BINARYEXEC-depends.txt $(PRE_DEFINED_DIR)/$$BINARYEXEC ; \
   ifeq ($(shell $(PATH_TO_GREP_EXE) "Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found." $(PRE_DEFINED_DIR)/$$BINARYEXEC-depends.txt)); \
      @echo "Dependency ok" ; \
   endif ; \
done
```

Comment: GNU make suggests the syntax to be correct. i.e. ifeq(arg1,). Source : http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_7.html (removed it and it didn't fix the problem nevertheless).