# If Else syntax evaluating wrong clause in GNU Makefile

Tags: bash, if-statement, gnu-make

I am trying to get if else syntax working in Makefile

```
TYPE=src
RTL=src

program_%:
ifeq ($(TYPE),$(RTL))  
        echo "RTL"      
else                    
        echo "Test"         
endif
```

Here is the  command line

```
$make -f test.make prog_src
```

and I get the following in the output

```
echo "RTL"
RTL
```

However, when i change the if statement such that instead of hard-coded variables I do something like

```
program_%:
ifeq ($(TYPE),$*)  
        echo "RTL"      
else                     
        echo "Test"
endif
```

and run as follows

```
$make -f test.make prog_src
```

I get the wrong clause evaluated

```
echo "Test"
Test
```

Comment: `ifeq` and `endif` is make syntax *only*. You can't use it in any part of a makefile that's evaluated by bash, as opposed to by make.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy removed /bin/bash from the code. Now how it might work?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did that and also formatted the code according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483313/make-error-for-ifeq-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the whitespaces in the condition

```
ifeq ($(TYPE),$(RTL))
```

#### Regarding the second part of the question:

No; this is not possible `ifeq` is evaluated in the context of the makefile and `$*` is not expanded there.  You can try `$(if ...)` but checking equality is not directly possible:

```
program_%:
    @echo $(if $(filter ${TYPE},$*),"RTL","Test")
```

"Context of makefile" means that `if*` sees only global make variables.  Special variables like `$*` are available in the rule context only.

#### Complex rules

complex rules are possible by

```
define complex_rule_A
@echo "complex_rule_A"
@echo "done"
endef

define complex_rule_B
@echo "complex_rule_B"
@echo "failed"
endef


program_%:
    $(if $(filter ${TYPE},$*),$(call complex_rule_A),$(call complex_rule_B))
```

#### Alternative solutions

When `${TYPE}` can be enumerated, a more clean solution might be

```
program_%:  .program_${TYPE}_%
    :

.program_RTL_%:
    echo else

.program_RTL_RTL:
    echo RTL
```

Comment: Bravo. This worked. Is there a way to get it to work without hard-coded variables.

Comment: I corrected the post. Please see the 2nd part of the post

Comment: Could you explain what does it mean in the context of Makefile and not in the context of Makefile since I thought $* is in the context of Makefile. I saw it in GNU Make manual

Comment: Lastly, I want to execute other statements if the condition is true and similarly other statements if the condition is false. For that how would I change your above syntax